# Find out the number of zeroes of $f(z) = e^z -3z -2 =0$ , inside $|z|=1.$

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

*In the first view I thought it to be a question of Rouche's theorem but when proceeded it was quiet tricky*

As **$f(z) = e^z- 3z- 2$**

*If we take $g(z)= - 3z-1$*

Then *$f(z) - g(z) = e^z - 2 = h(z)$ (say)*

*Now $|g(z)|= |-3z-1| > 3|z|-1 = 3-1 =2$
i.e $|g(z)|>2$  $(|z|=1)$*

And $|h(z)|=|e^z-1|<e^{|z|}-1<e-1<2$

*So $|h(z)|<2$ therefore*

Since $|g(z)|>|h(z)|$

Therefore **$Z(f)=Z(g)$**

Which is given as

$g(z)=0$

i.e., $-3z-1=0 \implies z=-1/3$ is the required zero of the given function

And the no. Of zeroes of the fn $f(z)$ is $1$

*Am I right kindly suggest*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
f(z)\in -1-2z+z^2B(0,e^1-2),
$$
$B(x,r)$ being the disk of radius $r$ around $x$.

This should be sufficient to apply the Rouché theorem, as $|1+2z|\ge 1>e-2$.

Comment: Ok but the way I approch was right or wrong kindly plzz tell

Comment: You were one step away from it. Considering $h(z)=e^z-1$ is not sufficient, you need $h(z)=e^z-1-z$, with then $|h(z)|\le e^1-2$ for $|z|=1$.